# Eloquent mass update model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to do 2 updates to a model Articles.

I want one update which i have written

```
     Article::query()->update([
         'isOnly' => !$value,
         ]);
```

This $value is based through a switch and it's standard, but for the second update, i want to update the articles only if it has votes, with the flag i have created in the articles migration called isVoted, so if a vote exists to an article this isVoted flag should be true.
Can this been written in a single query?

**Edit also the votes have an isOnly flag and should only count if the isOnly flag is equal to the !$value.

**Edit2 for clarification issues the isOnly flag means that the Article is getting voted alone at the current moment before the plenary session is started, so there are 2 votes, one where the Article is voted alone to see if it passes for the Plenary Sessios and two where the article is voted in the plenary session where the isOnly flag is false.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, if I understood you correctly:

```
$article = Article::query();

$article->update([
  'isOnly' => !$value,
  'isVoted' => !$value && $article->votes->where('isOnly', !$value)->count()
])
```

Comment: Can we do something like $article->votes::where('isOnly', !$value)->exists();
If this works it will solve my problem.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect but the logic can work. I haven't tried it before. I updated my answer. Please try it and let me know if it woked.